# GEE : Memory exceeded when plotting time-series at different regions

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to plot Sentinel-2 time-series at three different regions following the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection

```
// Reference data (ground truth) containing one merged polygon by class

var path = 'users/user/ROIs';
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection(path);
print(geometry);

// Load Sentinel-2 data

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");
var filtered = s2
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-01-01', '2021-12-25'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
    .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '30SYJ')
    .filterBounds(geometry);

// Select an index on the list ['NDVI', 'EVI', 'SAVI', 'OSAVI', 'NDMI', 'NDWI', 'MSI', 'MSI2']
var spectral_index = 'NDMI';
  
// Write a function for Cloud masking
// S2_L2A https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-2a/algorithm

function maskCloudAndShadowsSR(image) {
  var cloudProb = image.select('MSK_CLDPRB');
  var snowProb = image.select('MSK_SNWPRB');
  var cloud = cloudProb.lt(5);
  var snow = snowProb.lt(5);
  var scl = image.select('SCL'); 
  var shadow = scl.eq(3); // 3 = cloud shadow
  var cirrus = scl.eq(10); // 10 = cirrus
  // Cloud probability less than 5% or cloud shadow classification
  var mask = (cloud.and(snow)).and(cirrus.neq(1)).and(shadow.neq(1));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

var filtered = filtered.map(maskCloudAndShadowsSR);

// Add a band containing timestamp to each image
// This will be used to do pixel-wise interpolation later
var filtered = filtered.map(function(image) {
  var timeImage = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('timestamp')
  // The time image doesn't have a mask. 
  // We set the mask of the time band to be the same as the first band of the image
  var timeImageMasked = timeImage.updateMask(image.mask().select(0))
  return image.addBands(timeImageMasked)
});

// Specify the time-window
// This will determine how much backward and forward are we willing to
// look for an unmasked pixel in the time-series
var days = 30

// For each image in the collection, we need to find all images
// before and after the specified time-window

// This is accomplished using Joins
// We need to do 2 joins
// Join 1: Join the collection with itself to find all images before each image
// Join 2: Join the collection with itself to find all images after each image

// We first define the filters needed for the join

// Define a maxDifference filter to find all images within the specified days
// The filter needs the time difference in milliseconds
// Convert days to milliseconds
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// We need a lessThanOrEquals filter to find all images after a given image
// This will compare the given image's timestamp against other images' timestamps
var lessEqFilter = ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// We need a greaterThanOrEquals filter to find all images before a given image
// This will compare the given image's timestamp against other images' timestamps
var greaterEqFilter = ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

// Apply the joins

// For the first join, we need to match all images that are after the given image.
// To do this we need to match 2 conditions
// 1. The resulting images must be within the specified time-window of target image
// 2. The target image's timestamp must be lesser than the timestamp of resulting images
// Combine two filters to match both these conditions
var filter1 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, lessEqFilter)
// This join will find all images after, sorted in descending order
// This will gives us images so that closest is last
var join1 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: false})
  
var join1Result = join1.apply({
  primary: filtered,
  secondary: filtered,
  condition: filter1
})
// Each image now as a property called 'after' containing
// all images that come after it within the time-window
print(join1Result.first())

// Do the second join now to match all images within the time-window
// that come before each image
var filter2 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, greaterEqFilter)
// This join will find all images before, sorted in ascending order
// This will gives us images so that closest is last
var join2 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'before',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
  
var join2Result = join2.apply({
  primary: join1Result,
  secondary: join1Result,
  condition: filter2
})

// Each image now as a property called 'before' containing
// all images that come after it within the time-window
print(join2Result.first())


// Do the interpolation

// We now write a function that will be used to interpolate all images
// This function takes an image and replaces the masked pixels
// with the interpolated value from before and after images.

var interpolateImages = function(image) {
  var image = ee.Image(image)
  // We get the list of before and after images from the image property
  // Mosaic the images so we a before and after image with the closest unmasked pixel
  var beforeImages = ee.List(image.get('before'))
  var beforeMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(beforeImages).mosaic()
  var afterImages = ee.List(image.get('after'))
  var afterMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(afterImages).mosaic()

  // Interpolation formula
  // y = y1 + (y2-y1)*((t – t1) / (t2 – t1))
  // y = interpolated image
  // y1 = before image
  // y2 = after image
  // t = interpolation timestamp
  // t1 = before image timestamp
  // t2 = after image timestamp
  
  // We first compute the ratio (t – t1) / (t2 – t1)

  // Get image with before and after times
  var t1 = beforeMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t1')
  var t2 = afterMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t2')

  var t = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('t')

  var timeImage = ee.Image.cat([t1, t2, t])

  var timeRatio = timeImage.expression('(t - t1) / (t2 - t1)', {
    't': timeImage.select('t'),
    't1': timeImage.select('t1'),
    't2': timeImage.select('t2'),
  })
  // You can replace timeRatio with a constant value 0.5
  // if you wanted a simple average
  
  // Compute an image with the interpolated image y
  var interpolated = beforeMosaic
    .add((afterMosaic.subtract(beforeMosaic).multiply(timeRatio)))
  // Replace the masked pixels in the current image with the average value
  var result = image.unmask(interpolated)
  return result.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

// map() the function to interpolate all images in the collection
var interpolatedCol = ee.ImageCollection(join2Result.map(interpolateImages))

// Compute spectral indices.
var add_spectral_indices = function(image){
    // Sentinel-2 bands
    var s2_bands = 
    {'BLUE': image.select('B2'),
     'GREEN': image.select('B3'),
     'RED': image.select('B4'),
     'NIR': image.select('B8'),
     'SWIR1': image.select('B11'),
     'SWIR2': image.select('B12')
    };
    // Vegetation indices
    var ndvi = image.expression('((NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED))', s2_bands).rename('NDVI');
    var evi = image.expression('2.5*((NIR-RED)/(1+NIR+6*RED-7.5*BLUE))', s2_bands).rename('EVI');
    var savi = image.expression('(NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.5)*(1+0.5)', s2_bands).rename('SAVI');
    var osavi = image.expression('(NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED+0.16)*(1+0.16)', s2_bands).rename('OSAVI');
    // Water and moisture indices
    var ndmi = image.expression('((NIR-SWIR1)/(NIR+SWIR1))', s2_bands).rename('NDMI');
    var ndwi = image.expression('((NIR-SWIR2)/(NIR+SWIR2))', s2_bands).rename('NDWI');
    var msi = image.expression('(SWIR1/NIR)', s2_bands).rename('MSI');
    var msi2 = image.expression('SWIR2/NIR', s2_bands).rename('MSI2');
    // Add spectral indices
    var newBands = ee.Image([ndvi, evi, savi, osavi, ndmi, ndwi, msi, msi2]);
    return image.addBands(newBands);
};

// Map 'add_spectral_indices' function over the imageCollection.
var s2DataCube = interpolatedCol.map(add_spectral_indices);

// Select spectral indice band (default NDVI)
var s2DataCubeSI = s2DataCube.select(spectral_index);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: s2DataCubeSI,
          band: spectral_index,
          regions: geometry,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 10,
          seriesProperty: 'class',
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average ' + spectral_index + ' by Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true, size: 30}},
          vAxis: {
            title: spectral_index + ' (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['f0af07', '76b349', '0f8755'],
        });
print(chart);
```

However I obtain `User memory limit exceded` error. I'm able to solve the issue by making the polygons of the `FeatureCollection` smaller. However I would like to limit the maximum number of pixels used. Is there any way of doing this? How can I apply a `maxPixels` or similar so as not to overwhelm memory?

Comment: Include the complete script. How costly it is to generate this chart very much depends on the size your geometry and image collection.

Comment: @DanielWiell I added the entire script. I solved the problem using smaller polygons in my featureCollection, however I would like to limit the maximum number of pixels to use instead of reshape my polygons.

Comment: You also need to share your collection, otherwise we get an error 'Element (Error)
Collection.loadTable: Collection asset 'users/user/ROIs' not found". It is also helpful to include the link ("Get link" in code editor, so it will be faster to debug your script)

Comment: You can use the `scale` property to limit the number of pixels. To get more control, you might want to do a `reduceRegion()`, setting `maxPixels` to the max number of pixels you want to use, and `bestEffort` to `true`. That way, `scale` will automatically be set to ensure no more than `maxPixels` is used. https://code.earthengine.google.com/5a61dc7cfb88a812259da0ee42dc8bbf